# How to retrieve a column value using hibernate hql in grails

Tags: grails

I have table user(id,name,address) and User domain class.i want to get only the name of the user for the condition id=3.can i do with the findAll method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, User.findAll...{...} would always return you fully loaded user objects. If you need only name of the user, you can write HQL for the same. For example :

User.executeQuery("Select name from User where id=:id", [id:3]")